# Moving label position in mosaicplot() in R

Tags: r, axis-labels, mosaic

Given this example mosaicplot in R,

```
## create example data frame
set.seed(56)
df1 <- data.frame(Category1 = rep(c("Category name", "Longer category name", "Cat name"), times = c(42, 19, 6)), Category2 = sample(c("Low", "Mid", "High"), 67, replace =T, prob = c(0.25, 0.40, 0.35)))

df1

## make a contingency table
table(df1)

## make the mosaic plot
mosaicplot(table(df1), color = 1:3, las = 2, ylab = "Category2", xlab = "Category1", main = "")
```

How can I move the Category1 labels (edit: category names) upward so that the complete names are visible?

Comment: They appear visible to me. Am I missing something? http://i.stack.imgur.com/AJhXO.png

Comment: @MrFlick - I meant the category names, (ie "Longer Category name", "Cat name", etc), that wasn't clear. However, coming back to it now, it seems to be a problem of me not changing the window size of the graphics viewer. Should have tried that first! Both in R and Rstudio changing the window size makes the whole names visible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like @MrFlick, I can also see the labels. Have you changed your plot margins? Here's how to check:

```
par("mar")
[1] 5.1 4.1 4.1 2.1
```

I've pasted in the default margins (c(bottom, left, top, right)). If yours are smaller, it might not leave room for the labels. To reset them to the defaults (or whatever you want) do `par(mar=c(5,4,4,2)+0.1)`.

In any case, if you want to move the labels around, here are some examples:

```
mosaicplot(table(df1), color = 1:3, las = 1, main = "", xlab="", ylab="")
mtext(side = 1, "Category1", line = 0.5, col="green")
mtext(side = 1, "Category1", line = 1, col="blue")
mtext(side = 1, "Category1", line = 2, col="red")
mtext(side = 2, "Category2", line = -1, col="purple")
```

[image]

**UPDATE:** To remove the axis labels, save the contingency table as an object and then set the `dimnames` attribute to `NA`. You can also, of course change or abbreviate the labels this way as well. For example, to remove the `Category1` labels:

```
## make a contingency table
tab1 = table(df1)
dimnames(tab1)[["Category1"]] = rep(NA, length(unique(df1$Category1)))

## make the mosaic plot
mosaicplot(tab1, color = 1:3, las = 2, ylab = "Category2", 
           xlab = "Category1", main = "")
```

**END UPDATE**

You might also like the `mosaic` function in the `vcd` package. It's more complicated, but it gives you more control over the details of the plot. `mosaic` uses `lattice` rather than base graphics, so all the adjustments to the plot need to be done with `lattice` or `grid`, rather than the base graphics functions or parameters:

```
library(vcd)
mosaic(table(df1), color = 1:3, las = 2, ylab = "Category2", 
       xlab = "Category1", main = "", 
       labeling_args = list(offset_varnames = c(left = 2, top=0)),
       gp = gpar(fill = 1:3))
```

See [this vignette](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/vcd/vignettes/strucplot.pdf) for lots of examples.

Comment: eipi10 thanks for this. See my comment above. How could I suppress printing the category names ("Longer Category name", "Cat name", etc) from within `mosaicplot()`?